# listbox1 to listbox2 looped from listbox1 using sql query? Is it possible?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a table named *tblPrice* on sql server with column *service* and *price*. I have two `listBox` on winforms.

User will add items in the `listBox1` and then user clicks a `button`.

SQL query will search all the items in the `listbox1` and if `listbox1` contains a value from the column service, the price for this service will be added to the `listbox2`.

I tried these codes but it doesn't add the prices to the `listbox2`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < listBServices.Items.Count; i++)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT price FROM tblPrice WHERE service = '@svc'",
                con.Connection);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@svc", SqlDbType.Text).Value = listBServices.Items[i].ToString();
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rd.Read())
    {
        float price = rd.GetFloat(0);
        listBPrice.Items.Add(price.ToString());
    }
    rd.Close();
}
```

Comment: `SELECT price FROM price`?

Comment: @Jimi sorry the table name is *tblPrice*

Comment: Now see: `WHERE service = '@svc'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT price FROM tblPrice WHERE service = @svc"
```

instead of

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT price FROM tblPrice WHERE service = '@svc'"
                                                                              ^    ^
```

Comment: hi sir tried your suggestion but I get the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.'`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was my mistake from the parameters. This code answered my questions. Thank you all :)

```
                for (int i = 0; i < listBServices.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT price FROM price WHERE service = @svc",
                                con.Connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@svc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = listBServices.Items[i].ToString();
                    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (rd.Read())
                    {                    
                        listBPrice.Items.Add(rd["price"].ToString());
                    }
                    rd.Close();
                }
```